# Create a tooltip for dygraphs javascript charts

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

I have some charts which are built in Dygraphs which have 20+ lines plotted.

This makes the legend pretty unreadable.

As such, is it possible to create a tooltip that shows the value of only the line you're hovering over at any given time?

Ideally, I would like to keep the existing legend and have an additional tooltip too.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [`highlightSeriesOpts`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#highlightSeriesOpts):

```
new Dygraph(div, data, { highlightSeriesOpts: {} });
```

and then hide non-selected series using CSS:

```
.dygraph-legend > span { display: none; }
.dygraph-legend > span.highlight { display: inline; }
```

See the [series-highlight demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/series-highlight.html) for a fully-worked example.